# Integration over a circle using (Cauchy's) integral formula

Tags: complex-analysis

$$\int_{C[0,3]}^{}\frac{\sin(z)}{(z^2+1/2)^2}\,dz$$ is the integral I need to calculate.

I separated the integrand:
$$\frac{1}{\bigl(z-\frac{1}{\sqrt2}i\bigr)^2}\cdot\frac{\sin(z)}{\bigl(z+\frac{1}{\sqrt2}i\bigr)^2}$$

Consequently $$f(z)=\frac{\sin(z)}{\bigl(z+\frac{1}{\sqrt2}i\bigr)^2}$$ $$f'(z)=\frac{\cos(z) \bigl(z+\frac{1}{\sqrt2}i\bigr)^2-2\bigl(z+\frac{1}{\sqrt2}i\bigr)\sin(z)}{\bigl(z+\frac{1}{\sqrt2}i\bigr)^4}$$ and I use the integral formula $$\int_{C[0,3]}^{}\frac{\sin(z)}{\bigl(z^2+1/2\bigr)^2}\,dz = 2\pi i f'(w),\enspace  w=\frac{1}{2}i$$.

I got $$f'\Bigl(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} i\Bigr)=-\frac{1}{2} \cosh\Bigl(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\Bigr)-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \sinh\Bigl(\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\Bigr)$$ but this is wrong. I don't know why; I hope one of you can help me.

the answer is $\int_{C[0,3]}\frac{\sin(z)}{(z^2+1/2)^2}\,dz = 2 \pi i\sqrt2 \sinh\bigl(\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\bigr)$.

Comment: $$f'(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} i)=-\frac{1}{2} cosh(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})\color{red}{+}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} sinh(\frac{1}{\sqrt2})$$

Comment: the answer is 

$f'(\frac{1}{\sqrt2}i) = \sqrt2 sinh(\frac{1}{\sqrt2})$ so the fault still lies somewhere else

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Try again with following decomposition 
$$(z^2+\dfrac12)=(z-\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2}i)(z+\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2}i)$$

Comment: isn't that what I've done?

Comment: See radicals.!.

Comment: Aha, I had done that in my calculations but I edited my misstake now.

Comment: with what you wrote that produces the wrong answer, I think the problem lies elsewhere.